# Dynamically adjusting the DropDownHeight of a custom ComboBox C#

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, combobox, treeview

I have a custom ComboBox with a TreeView inside of it (modified from code [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jfoscoding/archive/2005/03/03/384430.aspx)), and am having issues with getting the DropDownHeight to correctly show everything.  Not only can I not get the initial DropDownHeight right (tried setting to treeview.height), but I would also like it to resize when a tree is opened to show everything without a scrollbar.  Is this possible?  Let me know if you need any more information!

Comment: @Shane.C See my comment for tranceporter's answer, that worked for width, but not height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bit of code in the link you provided should work:

```
private void ShowDropDown() 
{
   if (dropDown != null)
   {
      treeViewHost.Width = DropDownWidth;
      treeViewHost.Height = DropDownHeight;
      dropDown.Show(this, 0, this.Height);
   }
}
```

ComboBox automatically resizes itself based on the content it is rendering.

Comment: Yeah I have that code in there but it doesn't seem to work.  Not only does the width of the dropdown not match the width of the of the ComboBox (drop down ends up being like 80 while ComboBox is 180), but the dropdown height isn't right either.  I got the width part to work by changing the above code to `treeViewHost.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(DropDownWidth, DropDownHeight);` but it still didnt fix the height problem